# HTML5 sessionStorage or chrome.storage for Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, session-storage, google-chrome-storage

I have a Chrome Extension that is only a content script. I want to persist some data that is calculated in the content script so I can easily access it while browsing without having to recalculate it on each page. I only need the data to be stored for the session.

I was looking at the [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) but it seems data will persist there past the session. I have previous experience using HTML5 sessionStorage, but I feel like I should be leveraging Google's API here.

Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside a content script, using sessionStorage will access and modify the sessionStorage of that site, not of your extension.

You must use chrome.storage.local if you want it to be available to content scripts on other sites and to avoid breaking the sites.

There is no automatic clearing of chrome.storage.local data, but you can create an event page that clears it on startup.

manifest.json:

```
"background": { "scripts": [ "background.js" ], "persistent": false }
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
 chrome.storage.local.clear()
})
```

[chrome.storage.local.clear](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-clear)

[chrome.runtime.onStartup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup)

[Event Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)

Comment: Ahh, yeah that makes a lot of sense. To clarify, I must use google.storage but they don't have a session storage option so I have to implement my own session storage by deleting the local storage on every startup?

Comment: I am a bit confused on to structure this. The flow I'm going for is upon going to any subdomain of the domain I run some calculations and store the data (via chrome.storage.local) then when I go to any other subdomain under that domain I can access the data (via chrome.storage.local) inside the content script for that page. Would the code for storing the data be in the background.js or am I not understanding this?

Comment: You can modify the storage in both the background and content script. You may also want to use domains as storage keys.

Comment: Because the user can navigate to any of the subdomains first and I want the calculations to be run only once upon first entering the domain (doesn't matter which subdomain) I'm thinking to just put it in the background.js rather than putting it in each content script. Does that seam reasonable or am I missing something? Also what do you mean by using domain as storage keys? I only have one domain and just need to store one JSON object.

Comment: You could put in the background with the [tabs api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs), or the content script could check if the data already exists. I assumed you were handling more than 1 domain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123406/discussion-between-bagelboy-and-daniel-herr).

Comment: I have posted another question relating to this one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537741/chrome-extension-only-calling-content-script-once-upon-entering-domain. Could you take a look? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of Chrome 102+ there is now a session based storage API for Chrome extensions. It stores data in memory.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-session