# Handling specific tab state via a nested object in storage for a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension some data that I need to store is global but other data is local to each tab. Ideally there would be a way to store data per tab but sadly this doesn't exist.

In storage I'm using a `tabs` object where each key is a tab ID. Here tab ID1 has a status of 'yes' and tab ID2 is 'no'

```
  tabs: {
    1: 'yes',
    2: 'no',
  }
```

However this becomes unwieldy when I want to override one tab's data. To avoid overriding the other tabs data I need to read `tabs`, override the property, then write it:

```
  chrome.storage.local.get(['tabs'], ({ tabs }) => {
    tabs[1] = 'maybe';
    chrome.storage.local.set({ tabs });
  });
```

Listening for changes is also a bit verbose:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(({ tabs: { newValue, oldValue } }) => {
  if (newValue[1] !== oldValue[1]) {
    console.log(newValue[1]);
  }
});
```

Is there a better way to handle updating nested objects in storage or in generally handling tab specific state?

The other option I thought of was to save each tab ID as a top level key:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({
  101: 'yes',
  102: 'no',
});

setTimeout(() => {
  chrome.storage.local.set({ [101]: 'maybe' });
}, 1000);

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(changes => {
  const newValue = changes[101]?.newValue;
  if (newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
  }
});
```

This is easier to work with but feels like the lack of encapsulation could cause problems. Also while you can remove the relevant data when a tab is deleted this isn't 100% reliable eg if you force close Chrome. So stale data could get left in storage and perhaps over time this would become quite sizable.

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(tabId => {
  chrome.storage.local.remove([`${tabId}`]);
});
```

Comment: Use separate keys and perform a periodic clean-up to remove non-existent tab ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can store tabs states in sessionStorage.
Then when you want to retrieve them you'll have to send a request message to that tab.

Comment: Wouldn't that affect the website rather than my extension?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501435/html5-sessionstorage-or-chrome-storage-for-chrome-extension

Comment: If you're talking about content scripts then the answer is yes.
I seem to have done something similar before.
If I remember correctly I had added a prefix to the session variable name (like the extension id).
Once the tab is closed, everything flies away, so it doesn't seem like a big deal to me.

Comment: DOM storage like sessionStorage may be disabled by site's CSP or by the browser's global option like "Block all cookies by default" so this is not reliable. Also, non-web tabs like chrome:// or the start page or other extension's pages aren't injectable.